# Nginx/Owncloud not accessable from outside my local network

Tags: linux, networking, web, nginx, raspbian

I've got a Raspberry Pi with Nginx and Owncloud installed.

I forwarded ports 80 and 443 in my router.
When I type my DDNS adress on my Pi, it opens my Owncloud page without any problems, but from outside m y local network, it doesn't work. (Browser just gives me connection error)

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf: http://paste.ofcode.org/EL4EBrh97u66zMHPvZVpGv
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default: http://paste.ofcode.org/KpAaEPz5J7YwSgt4PSh7h2

Would really appreciate any help! :)

Comment: Do you know if your ISP blocks inbound traffic on those ports?

Comment: I'll phone my ISP this evening and post it here asap

Comment: Many of the tech support people for residential ISPs have no idea if they enforce such a policy. I had one person tell me it is impossible to block inbound port 80, yet their company was blocking port 80. You could try putting the router behind some other router then use something `nmap` to see if you can get through. That would confirm the router is working as expected.

Comment: Actually tech support responded now and they told me they arent blocking any ports except port 25.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm doing this for a friend who hasn't got any other routers and just access to his devices over the port forwarded SSH and RDP connections :S